# clearing a material-UI autocomplete field on the press of a button

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using material-UI autocomplete for a project that involves rendering a dynamic array based on what you select from the menu. I am finished with the project and now trying to implement multi-select to make choosing things from the menu easier. When you have everything you want from the menu, you click an "Add" button that takes everything you currently have selected and adds it to a table (and adds the properly formatted text into a query on the side, the goal is to build queries for users without them worrying about syntax). When I was not using multiselect, and only adding one thing at a time to the query, I was easily able to clear the autocomplete field by changing the value prop to null. This prevents users from adding the same fields to the query over and over (when add is clicked the options that were added are popped from the list of options). When using multi the rules seem to change and now changing value directly causes an error. My question is, does anyone know of a way to programattically click the x button built in to material-ui autocomplete fields to clear that text field in an event handler? Or is there any reliable way of clearing that on my end?

Comment: Can you share some code to give more context?

Comment: Changing the value still works for multiple, but the value for multiple should always be an array; so to clear it, set the value to an empty array: `[]`.

Comment: @DevonF Please include a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem and include the relevant code in your question text as well.

Comment: Please reproduce and post a link to your snadbox